# How to fix unbound local error on django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I have written this code. Every time I assign a variable I am getting "local variable 'obj' referenced before assignment". I don't know where I did wrong.

This is my view.py file:

```
def blog_detail(request, slug):
    queryset = Blog.objects.filter(slug=slug)
    if queryset.count() == 1:
        obj = queryset.first()

    templates = "temp_app.html"
    context = {"object": obj}
    return render(request, templates, context)
```

Here is my models.py file

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField()
    content = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

every time I run the server I am getting UnboundLocalError. 
bt if I use "queryset" without assigning it into "obj" I don't get the error.
I am getting the error after assigning the "queryset" in "obj". Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

That mean you should add the `obj` variable before `if` conditional. In your case, the result of `queryset` variable is not `1`.

```
queryset = Blog.objects.filter(slug=slug)
if queryset.count() == 1:
    obj = queryset.first()
```

to;

```
obj = None # or whatever your need.
queryset = Blog.objects.filter(slug=slug)
if queryset.count() == 1:
    obj = queryset.first()
```

or;

```
queryset = Blog.objects.filter(slug=slug)
if queryset.count() == 1:
    obj = queryset.first()
else:
    obj = None # or whatever your need.
```